# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

1. [Why does islam encourage covering female bodies?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76510/why-does-islam-encourage-covering-female-bodies)
2. [Why does the holy Q'uran begin with "In the name of Allah , the Compassionate, the Merciful."?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76579/why-does-the-holy-quran-begin-with-in-the-name-of-allah-the-compassionate-t)

I have two down votes on each of these two questions.

However, I don't know how to improve them.

Can anyone please explain?